# Storing logs in postgres database as text vs json type

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

Let's say we want to create a table to store logs of user activity in a database. I can think of 2 ways of doing this:

1. A table having a single row for each log entry that contains a log id, a foreign key to the user, and the log content. This way we will have a separate row for each activity that happens.
2. A table having a single row for the activity of each unique user(foreign key to the user) and a log id. We can have a `json` type column to store the logs associated with each user. Each time an activity occurs, we can get the associated log entry and update its JSON column by appending the new activity to it.

Approach 1 provides a clean way of adding new log entries without the need to update the old ones. But querying such a table to get the activity of a user would query the entire table.

Approach 2 adds complexity to adding a new user activity since we would have to fetch and update the JSON object but querying would just return a single row.

I need help to understand if one approach can be clearly advantageous over the other.

Comment: I guess, for point 1. save the logs as csv, query the files wit fdw... I remember an aws engenier who made some scripts to import the logs (in csv) to a table ( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/working-with-rds-and-aurora-postgresql-logs-part-1/ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databases are optimized to store and retrieve small rows from a big table. So go for the first solution. Indexes make joins like that fast.

Lumping all data for a user into a single JSON object won't make you happy: each update would have to read, modify and write the whole JSON, which is not efficient at all.

Comment: Do you know benchmarks for postgresql to store some logs? What is the capacity of PostgreSQL to store logs?

Answer (score 1):

If you logs changes a lot, in terms of properties, I would create a table with:

`log_id`, `user_id` (fk) and `log` in json format with each row as one activity.

It won't be a performance problem if you index your table. In postgresql you can index on fields inside a json column.

Approach 2 will become slower to update after each update, as the column size grows. Also, querying will be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider a logging framework that can [parse semi-structured data into database columns](https://github.com/b00ted/serilog-sinks-postgresql), such as Serilog.

Otherwise I would also recommend your option '1', a single line per log with an index on the user_id, but suggest adding a timestamp to your columns so the query engine can sort on the order of events before having to parse the json itself for a timestamp:

```
CREATE TABLE user_log
(
    log_id             bigint, -- (PRIMARY KEY),
    log_ts             timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT(now()),
    user_id            int NOT NULL, --REFERENCES users(user_id),
    log_content        json
);
CREATE INDEX ON user_log(user_id);

SELECT user_id, log_ts, log_content => 'action' AS user_action FROM user_log WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY log_ts;
```